# Custom Navigation slider

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make a custom navigation drawer in android.
It should compromise of a spinner view for selecting city from the list, then city temperature and then name, email and contact no.

I'm able to make city option and edit text list for name, email etc. Now I can't insert temp details in it.

need help

Comment: Post what you have done already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing animation of your slider

```
public static void playcloseanimationofleftdrawer() {
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2.0f));
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
        animation.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
        animation.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        animation.setDuration(500);
        leftdrawer.startAnimation(animation);


    }
```

Opening animation of your slider

```
 public static void playopenanimationleftdrawer() {
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -4.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2.0f));
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
        animation.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
        animation.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        leftdrawer.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think how you can achieve that!Anyway giving you how to do it.First make relative layout inside your layout,call that relative layout lets say left drawer.After which give that new created layout a color,basically you might want to give white color,ok next step is to give the height of relative layout

```
match_parent or fill_parent
```

and the width of your layout should be fixed size...or if you want your drawer to be from start of screen to end of screen you can still use above written code.So after all this all you have to do is to put a button above your created layout(most useful button is ToggleButton as it have 2 states to be pressed(on/off)) and that button will make your created layout to go either VISIBLE or INVISIBLE,so here you have custom sliding drawer where you can put any widget you like and put some translate animation onto it to make it fell real drawer.Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my Main Activity i am to hide the action bar and supposed to  open the drawer by clicking on text within the frame(not the app title)

Comment: you can do whatever you want as you creating your own layout so place button wherever you want

Comment: Helped me alot. Can you kindly help me with opening and closing this custom layout from MainActivity. Thnx

Comment: just do VISIBLIE and INVISIBLE like this

Comment: yourlayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) and if you want to make it visible on click do same with VISIBLE parameter

Comment: sure no problems don't hesitate take it as helped answer:)

Comment: i would advice you sliding animation so it feels more like sliding panel,i can give you a code if you need

Comment: It will be great for my project. Kindly do share.

Comment: sure on my way.Putting both,opening and closing of lets say your LEFT DRAWER